# using aligned or split inside align*

Tags: align, mathtools

I am trying to use `aligned` or `split` inside an `align*` environment.  However, I keep getting an error missing `}` or missing `\right.`.  However, this isn't the case.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\newcommand{\unit}[1]{\hat{\mathbf{#1}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
  \nabla\times\mathbf{F} &=
  \begin{aligned}
    \frac{1}{h_1h_2h_3}\left[h_1\unit{u}_1\left(
        \frac{\partial}{\partial u_2}(h_3F_3) - \frac{\partial}{\partial u_3}
        (h_2F_2)\right) &+ h_2\unit{u}_2\left(
        \frac{\partial}{\partial u_3}(h_1F_1) -
        \frac{\partial}{\partial u_1}(h_3F_3)\right)\right.\\
      &\left.+ h_3\unit{u}_3\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial u_1}(h_2F_2) -
        \frac{\partial}{\partial u_2}(h_1F_1)\right)\right]
  \end{aligned}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

If I removed `aligned`, `\right.`, and `\left.`, the document formats correctly so I know there isn't a missing `}`.  I have added in the `\right.` and `\left.` to correspond with breaking of the equation so that isn't missing either.

Comment: You can't have `\left` in one cell and `\right` in another one.

Comment: Your parentheses are not correctly balanced before a new row.

Comment: problem is, `\left` and `\right` have to be matched within *cells*, not just within lines.  you have two instances of `\left` in the input line just after `\begin{aligned}`, but only one of them is closed before the `&` two lines down; instead, it's closed just before the double backslash.  move that last closure to before the `&` and all should be well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have

```
\begin{aligned}
    <...> \left[ <...> \left( <...> \right) & <...> \left( <...> \right)\right.\
```

which is illegal: you can't have `\left` before a `&` and the matching `\right` after it.

Use `\biggl` and `\biggr`. I'd underline the symmetry of the terms by using three rows. Notice also the `[t]` specifier for `aligned`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\newcommand{\unit}[1]{\hat{\mathbf{#1}}}
\begin{document}
\[
\nabla\times\mathbf{F} =
  \begin{aligned}[t]
    \frac{1}{h_1h_2h_3}
    \biggl[ & h_1\unit{u}_1
      \biggl(
        \frac{\partial}{\partial u_2}(h_3F_3) - \frac{\partial}{\partial u_3}
        (h_2F_2)
      \biggr)+{}\\
    & h_2\unit{u}_2\biggl(
        \frac{\partial}{\partial u_3}(h_1F_1) -
        \frac{\partial}{\partial u_1}(h_3F_3)\biggr)+{}\\
    &h_3\unit{u}_3\biggl(\frac{\partial}{\partial u_1}(h_2F_2) -
        \frac{\partial}{\partial u_2}(h_1F_1)\biggr)\biggr]
  \end{aligned}
\]
\end{document}
```

Of course, for a single equation (even if split across lines) you shouldn't use `align*`.

[image]

Comment: I added the `newcommand` for `\unit` but don't worry about updating your post.  Also, in my `align*`, I have multiple equations but I only extracted the portion that was relevant to my question.

Comment: @dustin I had to fix a couple of small bugs anyway.